# ExpressJS Multi-Server CORS issue

Tags: javascript, rest, express, cors

I have a frontend server (using VueJS) that is hosted on Vercel, and then I have my backend as a service worker using HerokuApp. Now they both use the same custom domain (maev.me), but I would like to have a CORS rule so I can make it so that requests can only be sent from a domain/subdomain to the api.

The api is on one server, on the URL `api.maev.me`, and the frontend is on just the normal URL `maev.me`.

Is there any way to try and setup an ExpressJS CORS rule? I have tried using this regex I made:
`^.+\.+maev\.me$`

But that still doesn't work and spits out the error:

```sh
[Error] Origin https://www.example.me is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.example.me/me due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin https://www.example.me is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (me, line 0)
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex is that it doesn't match `https://maev.me` because of the literal `.`

Try using an array of mixed string literal and regex

```js
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["https://maev.me", /^https:\/\/.+\.maev\.me$/]
}))
```

---

Keep in mind that CORS is not access control. This won't prevent non-browser clients from accessing your API.

---

After your update, I checked your API via curl and everything seems correct as far as CORS headers go

```bash
curl -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://maev.me" "https://api.maev.me/"
```

> < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://maev.me

```bash
curl -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://foobar.maev.me" "https://api.maev.me/"
```

> < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foobar.maev.me

```bash
curl -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: https://example.com" "https://api.maev.me/"
```

> [no access-control-allow-origin]

Any other errors are not related to your CORS configuration

Comment: Cool, will check it out - thanks a lot :)

Comment: Now my API just says Internal Server Error - but my frontend is fine?

Comment: What do the server-side logs say?

Comment: Same error as in the question

Comment: No, that's a client-side log. If your API is responding with a 500, it's something wrong on the API side. Check your Express app's logs / console output

Comment: I’ll sleep on it and get back to you, thanks a lot <3

Comment: The `/\.maev\.me$/` regex allows insecure origins.

Comment: @jub0bs it only allows origins controlled by OP which is what they wanted

Comment: @Phil Sometimes, the OP doesn't know what's good for them. My issue is that the likes of `http://foo.maes.me` (note the `http` scheme) are allowed. And, unless that domain uses HSTS, allowing such insecure origins opens the door to this kind of attack: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgkj4ZgxI4c&t=21m20s

Comment: @jub0bs fair call and thanks for the link. I've updated the regex